# Установить куки на час

Tags: cookie, javascript

Вот есть такая строка, как мне её исправить, чтобы куки записывались всего на час?

```
exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (expDays*24*60*60*1000));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть мнение, что

```
exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (60*60*1000))
```

Чисто по логике, что expdays - переменная с количеством дней, 24 - часов в сутках, 60 - минут в часе, 60 - секунд в минуте, 1000 - миллисекунд в секунде.

Comment: @MopDa, т.е. должно быть так - exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (expDays*60*60*1000));?

Comment: Сколько миллисекунд в часе, столько и пишем после плюса (или считаем 60 на 60 на 1000).

Comment: Я имею ввиду переменную expDays писать?

Comment: Если вам нужно, чтоб куки сохранялись на столько часов, сколько задано в переменной expDays, тогда, несомненно, писать.

Comment: Переменная равна 1, т.е чтобы куки запоминались на час, нужно написать exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (60*60*1000))
и ничего больше (без переменной), правильно?

Comment: Если изначальный вариант записывал куки на expDays дней, то вариант в вашем последнем посте, по моему разумению, должен заставить их писаться всего на час, да.